# Redefine mixin default values LESS Magento 2

Tags: css, gruntjs, less, magento2

I'm working with LESS and Magento 2.In _navigation.less exist a mixin called .lib-main-navigation-desktop() with some default values, per example:

```
.lib-main-navigation-desktop(
    @_nav-background-color: @navigation-desktop__background,
    @_nav-border: @navigation-desktop__border,
    @_nav-font-size: @navigation-desktop__font-size,
    @_nav-font-weight: @navigation-desktop__font-weight
) {

    .navigation {
        .lib-css(background, @_nav-background-color);
    }
}
```

And I want to use this mixin with some different default values, per example the background-color. So, in my _extend.less file I added:

```
.lib-main-navigation-desktop(
    @_nav-background-color: red
) {
    .navigation {
        width: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

After bin/magento cache:clean, grunt:exec and grunt:less. The background is not changed. Instead of the this example, if I set the @navigation-desktop__background: red outside the mixin parameters, it works.

The example that I'm showing is not the proper way to do it?
I'm trying do it as in documentation on http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/theme-ui-lib.html#fedg_using-ui-lib_customize

Thanks.

Comment: In your example above you actually *define* a new mixin (that cascades to the default definition), while in their example they simply *call* the mixin with the [named argument(s)](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-named-parameters). I.e. notice the `.definition() {}` vs. `.call();` syntax difference.

Comment: I.e. per their example you'd simply do `.lib-main-navigation-desktop(@_nav-background-color: red);`. So it's not clear what you tried to achieve by adding that `{.navigation {}}` thing after.